# Can a new[] *char be delete[](ed)?

Tags: c++

is there any way to free the memory used by `*data` in this code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

class mstring {
public:
    char *data;
    int length;

    mstring::mstring()
{
    length = 8;
    data = new char[length];
    data = "UNKNOWN";
    cout << "In mstring default ctor" << endl;
}

mstring::~mstring()
{
    delete[] data;
    cout << "In mstring dtor" << endl;
}

};
int main() {
    mstring a;
    cout << a.data;
}
```

The code crashes when trying to delete as "UNKNOWN" can't be deleted.

Comment: You need to enable more compiler warnings and get better learning material.

Comment: You do _not_ use `strcpy()` to 'delete' a `char *`!  (At one time, it said: _[I] am aware of the fact that in order to simply delete a `*char` I have to use `strcpy`_)

Comment: Try using `std::string` it really makes your life a lot easier

Comment: `data = new char[length];
    data = "UNKNOWN";` creates a memory leak.

Comment: I meant use strcpy to put "UNKNOWN" into data, then delete[]ing it - which doesnt result in an error.
The compiler doesnt seem to show me any warnings there I think.

Comment: You don't respect rule of 3/5/0.

Comment: one cannot stress enough what @BaummitAugen said: No-one that learned C++ in a sensible matter would make the same approach here; it looks like someone is copying and pasting together C++ and C fragments that he/she didn't understand.

Comment: @Akra: Please edit the question so it says what you mean rather than saying in the comments what it should mean.  You can edit your own question.

Comment: also, your `class` definition doesn't make sense; I thing `mstring::mstring` is **meant** to be your constructor, but that's not how scoping works

Comment: @MarcusMüller Some compilers accept member methods which are prefixed with the class-name when they are defined in the class itself. It's an ugly extension, though from time to time you can find such code

Comment: @JVApen I didn't know that! This sounds like it could create pitfalls, ugly indeed. Also, notice that there's at least one `}` missing in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies within the following code:

```
data = new char[length];
data = "UNKNOWN";
```

First, you create a new char-array, in the next statement, you loose the only anchor point to it, by overriding it with the address of the literal string "UNKNOWN", which is stored inside of the executable.

When you end up in your destructor, you are trying to delete the memory of your executable, as you no longer refer to the allocated memory.

As you can't use `std::string` or `strcpy`, I guess you have to write it yourself:

```
auto fixedUnknownString = "UNKNOWN";
assert(fixedUnknownString[length] == '\0'); // Lucky coinsidence, extra code required if we wouldn't have an exact match
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    data[i] = fixedUnknownString[i];
}
```

Comment: So is there no need to free the allocated memory? or is it a logical error?
This is a college task, and I can only initialize data this way, according to the task.

Comment: Yes, there is a need to free the allocated memory, though you have lost your pointer to it, so you can't free it any more.

Comment: @Akra: It's a logical error.  If you can't use `strcpy()`, you'll have to simulate it to transfer the bytes of `"UNKNOWN"` (including the null byte) to the allocated `data` array.  Then the `delete[] data;` will work.  At the moment, you don't have any record of what was allocated (because of the memory leak), so you can't delete it.

Comment: Or simply don't allocate, if you only refer to a fixed string (at compile time)

Comment: you don't need to store anything in the memory pointed to by `data` to be able to delete it. however, you must give delete the original pointer value from new.